# number of strings in strings.xml?

Tags: android, string

i'm trying to collect all the strings in my app and save them in a key-value pairs .
i just need to know if it is possible to get the number of strings in strings.xml file and if there is a way please let me know ??

in the following i've tried to find one string but i need all of them :

```
private String getStringResourceByName(String str) {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(str, "string", packageName);
    if (resId == 0) {
        return str;
    } else {
        return getString(resId);
    }
}
```

Comment: `key-value pairs` sounds like SharedPreferences, to me...

Comment: exactly !! @FrankN.Stein

Comment: So... can't you simply use the normal SharedPreferences, instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: First, you can have several XMLs that define your strings, not only strings.xml. And second, why would you want to do this? I see no practical use for this.

Comment: what i meant with key-value pairs  is to use SharedPreferences @FrankN.Stein

Comment: i just need to know if there is a way to do it instead of the xml thing (in programmatic way i mean ) @m0skit0

Comment: You might want to programmatically read the SharedPreferences file, but... why do you want to overcomplicate an easy thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could use the [`Field`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) class.

```
Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
int size = fields.length; // If you want the size.
for (Field field : fields) {
    String str_key = field.getName();
    try {
        int id = field.getInt(null);
        String str_value = getString(id);
        // Store the String, and do whatever you want with it.

        Log.d("TAG","Key: " + str_key + " value: " + str_value);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("TAG",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`XPATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) and catch all the `<string>` tags

Here you have a [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/) about learning how to parse `xml` files with Java, and this [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html) about how XPATH works.

By the way, if you want to use key-value pairs, take a look to [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) too. Could be useful for your purpose.

Comment: i don't know anything about XPATH ... but i need to do it in a programmatic way like in java . thanks anyways :)

Comment: I've added some documentation to the answer which could be useful for you. Trust me, it's good to know about XPATH if you'll have to work with XML files ;)

Comment: aha Thank you very much :)